# How to get DOM-translated html with bindings of component in Angular 7?

Tags: angular, angular-template

Let's look at this simple example:

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-favorite-color',
  template: `<p>My favorite color is {{ favoriteColor }}</p>`
})

export class FavoriteColorComponent {
   favoriteColor: string = "red";

   getInnerHTML(){
   }
}
```

I expect getInnerHTML function to return:

```
<p>My favorite color is red</p>
```

How can i achieve that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can inject the [Element Ref](https://angular.io/api/core/ElementRef) in the constructor and access the nativeElement.

```
constructor(private el: ElementRef){}

getInnerHTML() {
  return this.el.nativeElement.innerHTML;
}
```